# Is it acceptable to use both 'written' and 'wrote' in the same surprising sentence?

Tags: past-tense, present-tense

> In that project I **wrote** the most complex code I had ever **written** in my life.

Is this grammatically correct?

Comment: did you forget "the most"

Comment: It doesn't make any sense to me, I'm afraid. The word that's causing me most trouble is *ever*. Should the ending read *...that I had never written in my life*? It seems also that you need an *in* before which. I am assuming it should read: *In was in that project, in which I wrote complex code and logging mechanisms; that I had never before written in my life*.

Comment: @JoeBlow Ah! Should it end: ...*the most I had ever written in my life*?

Comment: As @JoeBlow and noted, the sentence seems to be missing something. My first thought was "more" ("more complex code etc.," although that's ambiguous as to whether it's referring to greater code complexity or more lines of code).

Comment: i added the two obviously missing words, before "complex"

Comment: @JoeBlow first of all the question is proofreading and that's off topic on this site. Second, you cannot change the sentence that the OP is specifically asking about. Improve the formatting, the title, get rid of any typos that aren't in the citation if need be but leave the citation alone.

Comment: you're right, it's proofreading - deleted - and I can edit anything I want, there's an "edit" button!!!

Comment: more seriously: on ridiculously low-quality questions ... edit anything you want that helps it

Comment: @JoeBlow well why didn't you correct the blinking title then?

Comment: "usring" sounds like a new dotcom

Comment: figures! of course that's already a domain name http://usring.com

Comment: what are you guys saying?  If there is anything wrong with that sentence please fix it. That's all I want!

Comment: Do you folks need a definition of "proofreading"?  Seriously.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> "Yesterday I wrote the most complex code I've ever written in my life"

Seems fine. The two clauses are totally unrelated, so it's **just a coincidence** they both contain forms of "write".

(Incidentally. In my example sentence, I'm unsure if it's more betterer to include "which".)

Answer (score 0):

Your use of *wrote* and *written* is correct.

- *Wrote* is past tense, indicating that you wrote the code and logging mechanisms sometime in the past (relative to when you are writing/saying this sentence).
- *Had written* is the past perfect tense (*had* + past participle), which indicates something before the past previously referred to (i.e., before the project, which is itself in the past).